# Sonar Wall Display?

Tags: monitoring, sonarqube

My employer has installed two large LCD panels to display build health and statistics.

I'd like to display Sonar graphs which update intra-day. How's the best way of going about this? I've had a look through the available plugins and haven't found a "wall display" facility yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such plugin currently exists, and actually I'm not sure that this could be achieved with a plugin - as plugins can only contribute to the current Sonar UI.

Maybe you could send a mail on our mailing-list (user@sonar.codehaus.org) to tell your interest in such a feature for a future release of Sonar? Basically, this would be something like the possibility to ask the UI to show a Sonar dashboard outside of the standard layout and with a specific refresh rate.

FYI, we have planned a work on the UI for the next version of Sonar - 3.3, so this could be the opportunity to see if your need can be addressed within this sprint.

Comment: thanks. I'm going to write a simple UI that polls the Sonar API for now - will put on GitHub if it's any good!

Comment: Great, feel free to send a notification on the user mailing list if/when you put it on GitHub. Thanks!